# Problems with SSL to non-SSL htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I need some help with URL rewriting.

I need just 1 dynamic page (signin) to be handled via SSL, all other pages need to be redirected to HTTP.

So here my .htaccess file for :443 virtualhost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^signin$  https://www.page.com/?s=signin [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(signin)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

What happens is, that `https://www.page.com/signin` gets redirected via the *302 redirect* to `http://www.page.com/?s=signin`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is only your signin page https? doesn't that kind of default the purpose? Using https is good, but make sure you're using it correctly.

Comment: I think you should re-think the reasoning.  Sign in should be HTTPS but so should the logged in pages as well if your server can handle it.  The additional load is minimal for most traffic scenarios.  Why would you want to sign in securely and then stop using HTTPS?

Comment: SEO related stuff ... we just need some pages to be secure

Comment: You'll need an `[R]` flag on the first rule too. Though I don't think that will totally solve your problem. Also, be careful redirecting like this. It's easy to leak session information or cookies that are set via the https page that then become available over http.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged with PHP.  Is your signin page PHP?

Add this to the top of your signin page and that page will force itself to the HTTPS.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "") {
    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $redirect");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I take this as an apache question. To explain what seems to happen first:

Your first rule redirects to

```
https://www.page.com/?s=signin
```

This does not match the REQUEST_URI Condition !^/(signin)+; so the second rule redirects to

```
http://www.page.com/?s=signin
```

Probably your condition should read something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/\?s=signin [NC]
```

To see what exactly mod_rewrite does, enable the rewrite log, if you can - how to do this depends on the apache version.